# why aren't my images showing up

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs

Hi I'm trying to learn how to use the EaselJS libraries, eventually combining with some of the EXTJS libs butt I'm having trouble putting all my code in the .Js files. My js file looks like this

```
var democanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(democanvas);
democanvas.height = "400";
democanvas.width = "600";


function init() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("democanvas");
var stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas');
var im = new createjs.Bitmap("dbz.jpg");
 //  im.regX - im.image.width *.2; 
 //  im.regY - im.image.height *.2; 
stage.addChild(im);
stage.update();

im.addEventListener("click", function(){

var seed = new createjs.Bitmap("seed.jpg");
seed.alpha = 0.5;
seed.x = window.event.clientX;
seed.y = window.event.clientY;


stage.addChild(seed);
stage.update();
 }); //end seed evenlistener */

 } //end functin init()
```

this doesn't work, but if I comment out the whole document.createElement('canvas') section and I apply

```
 <body onLoad="init();">
<canvas id="demoCanvas" width="1000" height="1000">
    alternate content 
</canvas>
```

to my index.html file It will start working :( I included the .js within the body tag of te index html

Edit:::::::::::::::::::::: this is my current code, still not showing anything unless I add the canvas to the html page :(

```
window.onload = function (){
var demoCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
//document.body.appendChild(democanvas);
demoCanvas.height = "400";
demoCanvas.width = "600";
}

var stage;
function init() {
stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
var text = new createjs.Text("Hello World", "bold 86px Arial", "#ff7700");

stage.addChild(text);
stage.update();
}

init();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing - since you are using image paths, and not fully loaded images as Bitmaps sources, its possible the images are not ready when you update the stage. You can either put onload handlers on your image(s) to update the stage, or preload them first.

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = handleLoad;
image.src = "src.jpg";

function handleLoad(event) { stage.update(); }

// You can also use the Bitmap
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap("src.jpg");
bitmap.image.onload = handleLoad;
```

You can also tick the stage to update it constantly. This is a quick way to see if thats the problem.

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
// OR
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below :

```
document.body.onload = function(){

var democanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(democanvas);
democanvas.height = "400";
democanvas.width = "600";


function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("democanvas");
  var stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas');
  var im = new createjs.Bitmap("dbz.jpg");
   //  im.regX - im.image.width *.2; 
   //  im.regY - im.image.height *.2; 
  stage.addChild(im);
  stage.update();

  im.addEventListener("click", function(){

  var seed = new createjs.Bitmap("seed.jpg");
  seed.alpha = 0.5;
  seed.x = window.event.clientX;
  seed.y = window.event.clientY;


  stage.addChild(seed);
  stage.update();
   }); //end seed evenlistener */

 } //end functin init()

 init();
}
```

Comment: i'm getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null  error but thanks for the help! I'm going to try to fix that :)

Comment: I changed it to Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8, commenting out line 3 fixes it body.appendcild but it doesn't display anything still =(

Comment: `document.body.onload = function(){` in the beginning should fix it.

Comment: I added the call to `init();` at the end try again.

Comment: my apologies I forgot to copy that part.. I did use the init(); in the hello world.

Comment: with document.body.onload i still get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null  with window.onload no error but nothing shows up

Comment: try `document.onload` instead or `window.onload `

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to use the console of your navigator to see javascript's errors before any question.

You will see this error : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null**

That because you load **document.body.appendChild(democanvas);** before the html is load so your document.body is null.

This is the way:

```
function init() {
    var democanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(democanvas);
    democanvas.height = "400";
    democanvas.width = "600";

    var canvas = document.getElementById("democanvas");
    var stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas');
    var im = new createjs.Bitmap("dbz.jpg");
    //  im.regX - im.image.width *.2; 
    //  im.regY - im.image.height *.2; 
    stage.addChild(im);
    stage.update();

    im.addEventListener("click", function(){

    var seed = new createjs.Bitmap("seed.jpg");
    seed.alpha = 0.5;
    seed.x = window.event.clientX;
    seed.y = window.event.clientY;

    stage.addChild(seed);
    stage.update();
    }); //end seed evenlistener */

 } //end functin init()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using a preloader.
You can use the PreloadJS preloader like this:

```
    var preloader = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
    preloader.addEventListener("complete",this.handleComplete.bind(this));

    var manifest = [

        {src:"./images/yourIMAGE.PNG"},
        //another image

    ];
```

Comment: This is just an example. If you have questions how to use this let me know